# C- passing a tmp value through a function to another function

Tags: c

In This Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   /* for malloc */
#include <ctype.h>

#define STD_WORK_WEEK 40
#define OVERTIME_RATE 1.5


struct employee
 {
 char first_name[10];
 char last_name[10];
 long id_number;
 float wage;
 float hours;
 float overtime;
 float gross;

 struct employee *next;
 };

/************************************************************************/
/*                      Function: Gross_pay_calc                        */
/*                                                                      */
/*  Purpose:    Calculates gross pay of an employee using hours and     */
/*              wage data that is already stored                        */
/*                                                                      */ 
/*                                                                      */
/*  Parameters: wage - Array of employee wages                          */
/*              hours- Array of number of hours worked by an employee   */
/*              grossPay- Gross Pay of an employee                      */
/*              size-number of employees to process                     */
/*                                                                      */
/*  Returns:    Stores grossPay to be referenced in another function output  */
/*                                                                       */
/************************************************************************/

 /* Function call to calculate gross pay. */
 void Gross_pay_calc (struct employee *emp1)
 { 
  /*Local Variable Declaration */
  struct employee *tmp;   /* tmp pointer value to current node */

            if ( tmp->hours <= STD_WORK_WEEK ) /* Calculates grossPay based on <40 or     >40 for OT */

            {
            tmp->gross = tmp->wage*tmp->hours;
            }

            else

            {
            tmp->gross = (tmp->wage*STD_WORK_WEEK)+((tmp->hours-STD_WORK_WEEK)* (tmp->wage*OVERTIME_RATE));
            } 

   }

 /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 /*                                                                             */
 /* FUNCTION:  print_list                                                       */
 /*                                                                             */
 /* DESCRIPTION:  This function will print the contents of a linked             */
 /*               list.  It will traverse the list from beginning to the        */
 /*               end, printing the contents at each node.                      */
 /*                                                                             */
 /* PARAMETERS:   emp1 - pointer to a linked list                               */
 /*                                                                             */
 /* OUTPUTS:      None                                                          */
 /*                                                                             */
 /* CALLS:        None                                                          */
 /*                                                                             */
 /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 void print_list(struct employee *emp1)
 {
    struct employee *tmp;   /* tmp pointer value to current node */
    int i = 0;              /* counts the nodes printed          */

        printf ("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");         /*Print Header To Screen */
        printf ("     Name \t     Clock# \t Wage \t Hours \t OT \t Gross\n");
        printf ("---------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    /* Start a beginning of list and print out each value               */
    /* loop until tmp points to null (remember null is 0 or false)      */

    for(tmp = emp1; tmp ; tmp = tmp->next)
    {
        i++;

        /* TODO - print other members as well */
        printf("\n %s %s %6d %8.2f %5.2f %7.2f\n",tmp->first_name,tmp->last_name,tmp->id_number,
                                                  tmp->wage,tmp->hours,tmp->gross);

     }

     printf("\n\nTotal Number of Employees = %d\n", i);

  }

 /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
 /*                                                                            */
 /* FUNCTION:  main                                                            */
 /*                                                                            */
 /* DESCRIPTION:  This function will prompt the user for an employee           */
 /*               id and wage until the user indicates they are finished.      */
 /*               At that point, a list of id and wages will be                */
 /*               generated.                                                   */
  /*                                                                            */
 /* PARAMETERS:   None                                                         */
 /*                                                                            */
 /* OUTPUTS:      None                                                         */
 /*                                                                            */
 /* CALLS:        print_list                                                   */
 /*                                                                            */
 /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main ()
{

char   answer[80];       /* to see if the user wants to add more employees */
int    more_data = 1;    /* flag to check if another employee is to be processed */
char   value;             /* gets the first character of answer */

struct employee *current_ptr,   /* pointer to current node */
                *head_ptr;       /* always points to first node */

  /* Set up storage for first node */
head_ptr = (struct employee *) malloc (sizeof(struct employee));
current_ptr = head_ptr;

while (more_data)
{
   /* Read in Employee ID and Hourly Wage */

    printf("\nEnter employee ID: ");
    scanf("%li", & current_ptr -> id_number);

    printf("\nEnter employee weekly wage: ");
    scanf("%f", & current_ptr -> wage);

    printf("\nEnter employee weekly hours: ");
    scanf("%f", & current_ptr -> hours);

    printf("\nEnter First Name: ");
    scanf("%s", & current_ptr -> first_name);

    printf("\nEnter Last Name: ");
    scanf("%s", & current_ptr -> last_name);

    printf("Would you like to add another employee? (y/n): ");
    scanf("%s", answer);

    Gross_pay_calc(head_ptr);

    /* Ask user if they want to add another employee */
    if ((value = toupper(answer[0])) != 'Y')
       {
       current_ptr->next = (struct employee *) NULL;
       more_data = 0; 
       }
    else
       {
       /* set the next pointer of the current node to point to the new node */
       current_ptr->next = (struct employee *) malloc (sizeof(struct employee));
      /* move the current node pointer to the new node */
       current_ptr = current_ptr->next;
       }
} /* while */

/* print out listing of all employee id's and wages that were entered */


print_list(head_ptr);

  printf("\n\nEnd of program\n");

 return 0;
 }
```

I am trying to use gross_pay_calc to calculate the gross pay for each employee that I enter in the request. However, when I try to print the tmp->gross value in the print_list function, it does not calculate correctly. I am unsure why this is happening and would love any suggestions on how to make it calculate accurately!

Comment: In `Gross_pay_calc ` you're accessing memory through an indeterminate pointer, `tmp`. It is never set to valid memory before it is dereferenced, thus it is **undefined behavior**. Copy/Paste, ye are a ruthless and heartless wench. Try using the passed-in parameter `emp1` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things, first, your immediate problem. As mentioned in-comment, in Gross_pay_calc you're accessing memory through an indeterminate pointer, `tmp`. It is never set to valid memory before it is dereferenced, thus it is **undefined behavior**. Try using the passed-in parameter `emp1` instead:

```
/* Function call to calculate gross pay. */
void Gross_pay_calc (struct employee *emp1)
{
    if ( emp1->hours <= STD_WORK_WEEK ) /* Calculates grossPay based on <40 or     >40 for OT */
    {
        emp1->gross = emp1->wage*emp1->hours;
    }
    else
    {
        emp1->gross = (emp1->wage*STD_WORK_WEEK) + 
                      ((emp1->hours-STD_WORK_WEEK) * (emp1->wage*OVERTIME_RATE));
    }
}
```

Secondly, the algorithm for populating your linked list is overworked. A simple pointer-to-pointer can make that loop *much* more concise:

```
int main ()
{
    char answer[80];       /* to see if the user wants to add more employees */

    struct employee *head_ptr = NULL; /* the list head pointer */
    struct employee **next_ptr = &head_ptr; /*always holds the address of the next pointer to fill */

    do
    {   /* allocate new node wherever *next_ptr says to. initially it will be
           the head pointer. after that, the next-ptr of the last node added. */
        *next_ptr = calloc(1, sizeof(**next_ptr));

        /* Read in Employee ID and Hourly Wage */
        printf("\nEnter employee ID: ");
        scanf("%li", &(*next_ptr)->id_number);

        printf("\nEnter employee weekly wage: ");
        scanf("%f", &(*next_ptr)->wage);

        printf("\nEnter employee weekly hours: ");
        scanf("%f", &(*next_ptr)->hours);

        printf("\nEnter First Name: ");
        scanf("%s", (*next_ptr)->first_name);

        printf("\nEnter Last Name: ");
        scanf("%s", (*next_ptr)->last_name);

        Gross_pay_calc(*next_ptr);

        // move to the next pointer we'll be filling
        next_ptr = &(*next_ptr)->next;

        /* Ask user if they want to add another employee */
        printf("Would you like to add another employee? (y/n): ");
        scanf("%s", answer);
        if (toupper(answer[0]) != 'Y')
            break;

    }  while (1);

    // always set the last pointer to nothing.
    *next_ptr = NULL;

    /* print out listing of all employee id's and wages that were entered */
    print_list(head_ptr);

    printf("\n\nEnd of program\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Similarly, the print facility can be cleaned up a little as well:

```
void print_list(struct employee *emp1)
{
    int i = 0;              /* counts the nodes printed          */

    printf ("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf ("     Name \t     Clock# \t Wage \t Hours \t OT \t Gross\n");
    printf ("---------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    /* Start a beginning of list and print out each value               */
    /* loop until tmp points to null (remember null is 0 or false)      */
    for (;emp1; ++i, emp1 = emp1->next)
    {
        printf("\n %s %s %6ld %8.2f %5.2f %7.2f\n",
               emp1->first_name,emp1->last_name,emp1->id_number,
               emp1->wage,emp1->hours,emp1->gross);
    }
    printf("\n\nTotal Number of Employees = %d\n", i);
}
```

Comment: this is great, the only thing I am still a bit confused on is looping the gross_pay_calc. When I have more than one user that I need to calculate grosspay for, I am unsure of how to add that. I tried for(tmp = emp1; tmp ; tmp = tmp->next) but I think that's a bit off base. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Stuave You mean *cumulative* gross pay (as in, for *everyone* in one sum)? Or just calculate the gross pay for each person?. The latter is already done in the code above.